# On running in Ubuntu 16.04 ./createPeerAdminCard.sh it fails

Tags: hyperledger-composer

composer-cli v0.19.2 was successfully installed still on running this error occurs.

Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv11
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

No version of composer-cli has been detected, you need to install composer-cli at v0.19 or higher

Comment: Have you used root or sudo to install composer?  Can you execute `npm ls -g -depth=0` and post the output, and also `which composer`.

Comment: yes i have used sudo to install the composer.sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm composer-cli
[sudo] password for divyam: 
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
/usr/bin/composer -> /usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js
/usr/lib
`-- composer-cli@0.19.2 
  `-- tar@4.3.0
    `-- minipass@2.2.4
      `-- safe-buffer@5.1.2       And the output by this was npm ls -g -depth=0/home/divyam/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib
`-- npm@6.0.0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you install composer using root or sudo then it is not available to non-root users.

The pre-reqs doc for Composer warns not to use root or sudo, but the warning is actually missing in the install doc itself.

I would recommend uninstalling composer-cli (and playground, rest-server etc) with a command like `sudo npm uninstall -g composer-cli` then re-install without using sudo.  If you have permission problems with npm install there are [some notes](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#installissues) in the composer knowledge wiki.